# Designing pages with CSS disabled

Tags: html, css

I'm currently designing a site which uses a dark background, and just out of interest, I disabled CSS and took a look at it. Because it's been marked up semantically, without styles it's still a coherent document, except for the fact that my heading images are white, and because the default background colour is also white, you can't see the headings at all. (The headings are marked up as h1/h2/h3 and then Javascript replaces them with images).

Now I know this is a minuscule edge case of users who don't have CSS, but do have javascript, so this is a very much more theoretical rather than practical question, but should I go back to the old and outdated way of setting background colours:

```
<body bgcolor="#333333">
```

..so that you can still see the white images?

Comment: hmm white images on white text. you're not using transparent PNGs are you? if you are then you have bigger problems.

Comment: It's not such a theoretical question for sites that need to be Section 508 compliant.

Comment: In all honesty I cannot see why you would do this. As said by Eddie these methods were depreciated for a reason and there are very few users that use browsers that cannot handle CSS.

Comment: Not having javascript enabled is a far more common scenario than not having css enabled. You should replace headers with images using css rather than using javascript.

Comment: I imagine this is also a problem when printing, since the javascript will have replaced the text with an image that is likely to print without any background, as this is a common ua default.

Comment: @simon, re: Transparent PNGs.. yep they are.. screw IE6. @Kristian, if JS is disabled, then the user will still get the heading text, and that's fine with me.

Answer (score 10):

I usually insert the heading image via CSS too.

```
<h2 class="my-heading"><span class="hide">My Heading</span></h2>
```

and then

```
.my-heading {
    width: 100px;
    height: 24px;
    display: block;
    background: #fff url(image/my-heading.jpg) top left no-repeat;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

so that users in no-CSS environment got the text version one.

edit: Thanks for [d03boy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20471/d03boy) for providing a better alternative to do this (text-indent: -9999px;) and [Karan Bhangui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11110/karan-bhangui) for pointing out the missing stuff (my bad). Check comment section.

edit 2: Thanks [Traingamer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27609/traingamer). I'll be sure to double-check next-time. ;)

Comment: I use text-indent: -9999 to hide text

Comment: ya, the span is unnecessary as mentioned above. Secondly, doesn't the header need a `display: block`?

Comment: yup, that's a nice way too. As long as the text is hidden and the image brought in via CSS, well you got the point. :)

Comment: I'm sure you meant .my-heading rather than #my-heading - good answer, though. Using css for both the background and a default background color will give the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't.  Those attributes are deprecated for a reason.  There are better ways to work around these sorts of problems.  As others suggested, have Javascript detect if CSS is disabled so it won't make the changes in those cases.

Normal users who disable CSS expect to see things not exactly as the creator intended.  To handle users who are instead using alternate browsers (such as blind users) make sure you fully and accurately populate the ALT tags of images, etc.

Comment: what! if someone hasnt got css enabled are they likely to have javascript enabled

Comment: This is the case the author of the question is asking about.  I agree it's not likely.

Answer (score 1):

Add some intelligence to your JS.  I dont know how to do it in JS, but detect if CSS is disabled and then do something different in response. The JS is to blame for making your page unreadable, so it should have the solution.  Putting the fix in a style tag just causes more complexity.

For instance, someone without CSS very well might also not support a style tag!  Also, it could be a blind user with a screen reader, and them not having any text at all and an image instead is rather insulting.  Better set your ALT text etc.

Answer (score 1):

A non-coding solution:
How about adding a dark edge around the heading image? In normal dark background, the dark edge around the heading image/text won't be too obtrusive; meanwhile when css is disabled, the heading image/text is still readable as outlines.

Comment: Would be a headache though if the site use a non-plain background (eg. gradients). Nevertheless, good point.